# Cairo / GTK example code crashes when window is too big or maximized

Tags: gtk, mingw, cairo, gtk2, pixmap

I have copied and compiled the source code available in the section titled "Full Source".

http://cairographics.org/threaded_animation_with_cairo/

I adapted this code to a project that I'm working on only to find that the app would crash when I made the window too big.  Going back to the original example code, it too crashes when the window is too big (> 1000x1000 or so).

I narrowed down in the example that this line appears to be responsible:

pixmap = gdk_pixmap_new(window->window,500,500,-1);

Where pixmap is of type GdkPixmap*.  Resizing the window overwrites pixmap with a new pixmap that is the size of the window.

I am doing this in Eclipse Juno in Windows Vista, 32-bit.  My compiler is MinGW version 0.5-beta-20120426-1.  My GTK+ version is 2.24.10 and apparently Cairo is 1.10.2  I added all of the includes and libraries for GTK and also added compiler switch -mms-bitfields.

Is there a limit to the size of a pixmap or something?  I'm just starting with GTK with examples so I'm not sure where to go if this example doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with GTK 2.24.10 and cairo 1.12.2 on Debian, it works (no crash), with a maximized window on a 1280x1024 display. However, I'm aware that there is a [memory leak on GTK for Windows](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685959), which [has been fixed](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/?h=gtk-2-24&id=bb867e9406ee0d9e6109bfc4c33a38585c76a242) since GTK 2.24.14. Is your crash happening soon, or after some more time ? If it's crashing soon, that's another problem, otherwise just give a look at the memory consumption.

Compiling GTK with debug symbols would also help to narrow down the bug...

BTW, is `window->window` valid at the time the crash happens?